# woocommerce features to add product along with link

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I have used [woocommerce plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) for [this](http://buypcgamecdkeys.com/) site. Now you can see in the home page all the products are placed. At the top section there is one category named as All Products. In that category you can see there are 5 products with their percentage off, price and the buy now button is made. Now when user will click the buy now user will redirect to the product details page. Now my question is all of the things have been done in hard coding. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this so that admin will get the full feature to control it. Admin will upload all the picture and he will adjust all the price, discount text. So kindly suggest me how to do this? Is there any relevant plugin is available for this? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you need is WooCommerce, the one you already have installed and configured. No other plugin is needed to do what you're asking.

I'd suggest looking at the excellent documentation at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/